# extjs 4 dynamically enable an actioncolumn item

Tags: extjs4, gridpanel

Using 4.0.6 I have a gridpanel with an actioncolumn that has two items, a delete button and and view button. The delete button is disabled but there are some circumstances where it needs to be enabled (if a user is an admin). So I am trying to enable it in code.

Here's the view:

```
Ext.define('PP.view.person.List', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias: 'widget.personlist', 
title: 'Current people',
store: 'People',
columnLines: true,

initComponent: function () {
    this.columns = [
        { header: 'Id', dataIndex: 'personId', flex: 1, sortable: true },
        { header: 'Title', dataIndex: 'title', flex: 1 },
        { header: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', flex: 1},
        { xtype:'actioncolumn',
            items:[
                {icon:'cross.gif',disabled:true,handler:function(){alert('delete pressed');}},
                {icon:'tick.gif',handler:function(){alert('view pressed');}}
            ]
        }
    ];

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

});

and the controller function I'm using to enable:

```
enableDel: function () {
    var view = Ext.widget('personlist');
    view.down('actioncolumn').enableAction(0);
}
```

but I am getting an error inside the extjs enableAction function on the line that starts

```
me.up('tablepanel').el.select
```

the el is undefined. The column doesn't get enabled either. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or post an example that works? If I specify

```
renderTo: Ext.getBody()
```

in the view I don't get the error any more but the column still doesn't enable. So I think it must be something to do with rendering but I'm so new to this I haven't a clue where to start.

Comment: see if you can post your code into a jsfiddle. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/8f8EC/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when el is undefined it means that you are attempting to access it before the component is rendered.  When does your `enableDel` function get called? You might want to try putting it in an `afterrender` listener.

Comment: I was calling it from a button click although in fact the app would call it once it had worked out whether the user was admin or not. I put a listener in for afterrender on the actioncolumn and the grid and the viewport, all had fired long before I clicked my button. However if I call the enableDel function in any of those listeners it works. So it looks as if I was originally calling enableDel too late - I still don't completely understand. However I think I can work out whether the user is admin much earlier than I thought i.e. by the time any of the afterrenders fire.